# Movie Clip changing coordinates in XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, animation, movieclip

I have this xml copied from timeline:

```
private function move(function_mc:MovieClip, cx:Number, cy:Number){
        var move_xml:XML = <Motion duration="40" xmlns="fl.motion.*" xmlns:geom="flash.geom.*" xmlns:filters="flash.filters.*">
                <source>
                    <Source frameRate="24" x="0" y="0" scaleX="1" scaleY="1" rotation="0" >
                        <dimensions>
                            <geom:Rectangle left="0" top="0" width="23" height="23"/>
                        </dimensions>
                        <transformationPoint>
                            <geom:Point x="0" y="0"/>
                        </transformationPoint>
                    </Source>
                </source>

                <Keyframe index="0" tweenSnap="true">
                    <tweens>
                        <CustomEase>
                            <geom:Point x="0.2308" y="1"/>
                            <geom:Point x="0.9524" y="0.9524"/>
                        </CustomEase>
                    </tweens>
                </Keyframe>

                <Keyframe index="39" x={cx} y={cy} />
            </Motion>;

            move_animator = new Animator(move_xml, function_mc);
            move_animator.play();
}
```

What I want is to use this function for more movie clips, when I click specific button. But every movie clip has different start and end coordinates. I was trying send `cx` and `cy`, for example `cx = 20, cy = 0`, but every time I clicked on button, it only moves the movie clip in the x-axis. But I want to send the movie clip on coordinates `x=20` and `y=0`. And when I click the same button again, it will stay on `x=20` and `y=0`. Is there any way how to do it? 
Or any other solution, how to reuse animation for different movie clips and send them to different coordinates?
Thank you for your help.